# CSS transition different behavior depending on browser type

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

In my code I change the position of some elements based on the current mouse X & Y position. I added a css `transition: all 5000ms;` to make the animation smoother.

It looks great and works as expected in Google Chrome (version 63) but in the **Internet Explorer** and **Firefox** the animation looks laggy/choppy

Here is my code:

```
// $('.shape').css("transition", "all 7000ms");
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    let mX = e.clientX;
    let mY = e.clientY;
    $('.shape-1').css("transform", "translate("+mX/10+"px, "+mY/10+"px)");
});
```

Does anyone know why the browsers treat the css transitions differently?

JSFiddle **without CSS transition**: https://jsfiddle.net/2rrcp27L/9/

JSFiddle **with CSS transition**: https://jsfiddle.net/2rrcp27L/6/

Comment: join the future,drop support for internet explorer. focus on edge.

Comment: @Tschallacka But the effect is also very laggy in Firefox...

Comment: Why not use `transition: transform 500ms` instead of `all`?

Comment: @kumar i could do that, but its still not a fix for firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/2rrcp27L/11/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main reason why this is happening is that `mouseMove` fires a LOT of times, and Chrome can handle it but maybe Firefox is not, and IE definitely isn't, optimized to handle such cases.

You should [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle) your calls to the handler.

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/s2f9d77x/

Also, it'd be advisable to specify `transition: transform` instead of `transition: all` to tell the browser to not worry about other properties of the element.

Comment: You can play with different values for the throttle timeout to see which works best for your case. .

Comment: Also, as a best practice, maybe don't include the whole lodash package in your final website, but just the [lodash.throttle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.throttle) sub-package - if possible

Comment: even though I'm not a fan of including lodash for such a simple task (imo). It seems like the best solution. Thanks @kumar

Comment: You can roll your own throttle function if you like. I used lodash just to illustrate the point. Also, you can use just `lodash/throttle` in your project - no need for the full thing.

Comment: yep, I did just that, check my answer below. Thanks again @kumar_harsh

Answer (score 8):

The problem seems to be that the frequency of the mouse events - you set a new transform before the transition effect is finished. FF/IE seem to reset to last finished transition's values while chrome from current animation state.

A solution could be a combined setting of left and translate properties, like in the updated snippet, where you "simulate" the end of the transition by an updated left/top property. This is still a little bit jumpy as every mousemove will update instantly to previous mouse event but not that jumping anymore. If you want more control over the animation, you will have to write a by far more complex javascript.

```js
$('.shape')
   .css("transition", "transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 1.17, 1, 1)")
   .each(function() {
     $(this).data("left", parseInt($(this).css("left")));
     $(this).data("top", parseInt($(this).css("top")));
   });
 let factors = [
   [10, 10],
   [3, 3],
   [5, 5],
   [7, 7]
 ];
 let mX, mY;
 $(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {

   if (typeof mX !== "undefined") {
     $('.shape').each(function(idx) {
       let $shape = $(this);
       $shape.css({
         "left": $shape.data("left") + mX / factors[idx][0],
         "top": $shape.data("top") + mY / factors[idx][1],
         "transform": "translate(" + (e.clientX - mX) / factors[idx][0] + "px, " + (e.clientY - mY) / factors[idx][1] + "px)"
       });
     })
   }

   mX = e.clientX;
   mY = e.clientY;


 });
```

```css
body {
    background: #E1F7E7;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(169,232,220,1) 0%, rgba(225,247,231,1) 50%, rgba(169,232,220,1) 100%); /* ff3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(169,232,220,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(225,247,231,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(169,232,220,1))); /* safari4+,chrome */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(169,232,220,1) 0%, rgba(225,247,231,1) 50%, rgba(169,232,220,1) 100%); /* safari5.1+,chrome10+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(169,232,220,1) 0%, rgba(225,247,231,1) 50%, rgba(169,232,220,1) 100%); /* opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(169,232,220,1) 0%, rgba(225,247,231,1) 50%, rgba(169,232,220,1) 100%); /* ie10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(169,232,220,1) 0%, rgba(225,247,231,1) 50%, rgba(169,232,220,1) 100%); /* w3c */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a9e8dc', endColorstr='#a9e8dc',GradientType=1 ); /* ie6-9 */
}
.shape {
    position: fixed;
    transform-origin: center;
}
.shape:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: -25px;
    top: -50px;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 500px solid;
}

.shape-1 {
    top: 50px;
    left: 200px;
}
.shape.shape-1:after {
    transform: rotate(190deg);
    border-bottom-color: #A9E8DC;
}

.shape-2 {
    bottom: 300px;
    left: 250px;
}
.shape.shape-2:after {
    transform: rotate(19deg);
    border-bottom-color: #02BEC4;
}
.shape-3 {
    
    bottom: 380px;
    right: 220px;
}
.shape.shape-3:after {
    transform: rotate(-19deg);
    border-bottom-color: #0284A8;
}

.shape-4 {
    top: 200px;
    right: 180px;
}
.shape.shape-4:after {
    transform: rotate(-190deg);
    border-bottom-color: #050C42;
}

@media (max-width: 1450px) {
    .shape.shape-4:after {
        transform: rotate(-190deg);
        border-bottom-color: #02BEC4;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="shape shape-1"></div>
<div class="shape shape-2"></div>
<div class="shape shape-3"></div>
<div class="shape shape-4"></div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum magnam unde earum voluptas quae? Molestiae cum suscipit, esse placeat eligendi rerum nam minus inventore. Voluptatum impedit sunt quisquam officiis eius obcaecati totam aliquid incidunt
    vel aliquam. Nemo quae iusto perferendis corrupti provident sint quisquam, impedit nesciunt architecto a, ea necessitatibus!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, eveniet! Harum saepe quia inventore, atque dolorem culpa debitis. Blanditiis ad ab delectus, magnam assumenda sequi corrupti dolorum incidunt eligendi obcaecati magni! Veniam maxime
    ratione placeat veritatis excepturi. Nisi sed, dolorum, maxime laboriosam magnam vel aperiam beatae autem dicta, totam commodi? Modi, ratione tempore recusandae nulla suscipit quaerat earum repudiandae vero sit ad dolorem quasi, laboriosam culpa.
    Sequi, laboriosam assumenda? Aliquid esse impedit cum reprehenderit ex ipsa deleniti nam pariatur alias iusto sit tempore tempora eius optio voluptates veniam, laboriosam aliquam, odio corporis possimus nihil fugiat. Consectetur repellendus fugit
    dolorum ipsa ullam optio tempora maxime possimus, atque aut doloribus, iusto quam? Repellendus ipsa, praesentium tempore incidunt quasi cumque quidem nostrum harum non facilis doloremque voluptates quis architecto consequuntur consequatur. Illo, eius?
    Dolorem deserunt ipsam error voluptates necessitatibus iste dolor? Quo adipisci corporis incidunt fuga sapiente recusandae qui quod, impedit maiores! Eum blanditiis natus officiis inventore architecto! Aliquid quis praesentium doloremque laboriosam
    consectetur veniam excepturi inventore, exercitationem iusto sed, maxime sunt laudantium porro possimus esse? Dolor eveniet laborum aut tempore blanditiis voluptatem asperiores dolore incidunt, ipsa ea ut consequatur, itaque sint reprehenderit aliquam
    nesciunt debitis ex quia. Cupiditate beatae sapiente minima, fuga architecto, ad, aliquam provident et corporis tempore nostrum natus labore hic in eaque dolor perspiciatis nesciunt deleniti error unde. Sapiente nemo deleniti omnis quod odit accusamus
    obcaecati ea culpa ut fugiat, cumque vitae? Iste corporis quo illum nesciunt fugit quis officia consequuntur sit eum dignissimos. Necessitatibus autem eligendi quod quis tenetur, quos excepturi rerum repudiandae ullam magnam sequi consequuntur voluptate
    sint nemo ea, at tempora. Dolore consequuntur excepturi perferendis cumque tempore nam consequatur sit tempora cupiditate nisi magnam quos nulla nobis iste optio voluptas temporibus mollitia quibusdam hic, eaque vitae culpa dolorum error? Beatae numquam
    animi distinctio doloribus unde velit quasi quisquam necessitatibus reprehenderit vitae, obcaecati minus, tempora illo impedit ullam blanditiis vero excepturi ratione fugiat nemo? Quidem dicta perspiciatis iste cum, quisquam vel minima consequuntur
    blanditiis aperiam, sequi eligendi exercitationem inventore, eos facilis laborum beatae excepturi praesentium dolore quaerat assumenda quo obcaecati? Dolores, pariatur suscipit! Voluptate inventore assumenda delectus optio totam adipisci amet distinctio
    exercitationem sint debitis ea, vel deleniti odio odit. Illo adipisci, id, dolores culpa voluptatum eligendi fugit numquam quis accusamus possimus, ea odit laborum ullam non quasi! Dicta est aliquid saepe! In officia, dolor quo architecto illum repudiandae.
    Suscipit, pariatur sed commodi quod dolorem beatae quae!</p>
  <h2>What up?</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Itaque, dolor quam. Fugiat numquam eius animi omnis explicabo atque. Expedita velit unde iure earum, sit id esse provident odit illum recusandae deserunt laborum quis molestiae omnis! Laborum
    ea officiis exercitationem perferendis magnam temporibus eligendi porro earum nobis nesciunt. Ducimus quisquam commodi eum, pariatur, illo sint doloribus similique ea fuga porro sapiente, quam blanditiis. Veritatis quasi officia soluta explicabo nobis!
    Explicabo id voluptate quasi tenetur iste eum dolor illo, architecto, harum ad cum provident vero, saepe unde sed? Doloribus eaque pariatur sequi officia. Sit ipsam doloribus molestias ipsum adipisci recusandae explicabo sint ad rem magni, ducimus
    eligendi! Velit, dolore illo laboriosam ipsa, a sunt eum soluta nesciunt expedita porro atque maiores dolores amet temporibus nemo, cum hic libero autem ad? Nobis molestiae accusantium dolor aspernatur dolorem exercitationem reprehenderit quisquam
    est, fuga distinctio neque, iste, libero necessitatibus. Voluptatum aut ducimus autem magnam, quaerat iusto rem libero iste magni odio voluptatibus excepturi voluptates ab dolor laudantium nesciunt, ea, enim totam? Nostrum unde enim accusamus aliquid
    debitis sint amet commodi, iusto maxime distinctio. Nobis aut quae molestiae et architecto quo animi aliquam, vel iste, expedita, nihil praesentium voluptates soluta sed? Illum natus, aspernatur iure expedita beatae maxime eveniet perferendis laborum
    recusandae quo temporibus voluptate dolores fugiat at. Sit aperiam minus et nemo doloremque nihil, alias libero dolor dolorum commodi pariatur in atque deleniti distinctio recusandae molestias consequuntur consectetur sapiente ut cupiditate fugiat
    eveniet. Ad quo quaerat consequuntur recusandae excepturi debitis tempora temporibus atque amet iure.</p>
  <br>
  <h2>and Good Bye...</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum unde, necessitatibus laboriosam obcaecati cumque eum iure blanditiis voluptate temporibus possimus quam suscipit dolore dicta reprehenderit repellendus? Minima, voluptate voluptatum! Nostrum
    modi minus dignissimos, minima omnis eligendi adipisci eaque consectetur totam incidunt vitae reprehenderit, corrupti qui dicta soluta nihil! In quasi porro temporibus ipsum similique, aspernatur velit ullam laudantium id molestiae ut esse provident
    natus, eius iste earum ab corrupti, officiis distinctio eos repellat tenetur odio. Temporibus, eum! Aliquid libero doloribus necessitatibus consequuntur adipisci dicta ducimus quam qui odit atque eius voluptates repellendus illo non perferendis eum
    reiciendis dolor aliquam, excepturi voluptatum. Temporibus veritatis autem, numquam ab maiores cumque exercitationem. Porro minima quod magni blanditiis cupiditate dolorum dolores qui, ipsum voluptas nostrum, soluta modi nam harum atque aliquid ea
    totam accusantium consectetur quae? Libero ad at atque quisquam enim accusamus, perferendis provident sequi, blanditiis velit recusandae odio tenetur deserunt quo incidunt quam eaque perspiciatis fugit in unde non quidem, natus labore? Eveniet ducimus
    eius ullam! Aut aperiam enim, voluptatibus, harum cumque voluptas debitis voluptatem ullam placeat omnis et magni dolorem asperiores obcaecati quo deleniti delectus error incidunt possimus expedita maiores quisquam reiciendis? Unde, reprehenderit.
    Et natus ullam asperiores sapiente veniam sint.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the version from @kumar worked best for me

Answer (score 2):

After a while I found a solution that works best for me and it does not require any extra library (exept jQuery)

I basically created my own "throttle" function, that only updates the current x & y position of the mouse.

Here I attach the mouse position to the window object, everytime the mouse moves in the browser window:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var event = e || window.event;
    window.mouseX = event.clientX;
    window.mouseY = event.clientY;
});
```

Then I have another function, that sets the position of my elements:

```
function moveElements() {
   $('.shape-1').css("transform", "translate("+ window.mouseX/10 +"px, "+ window.mouseY/10 +"px)");
}
```

Finally, the `moveElements()` function gets called every 100 milliseconds, making use of the `setInterval()` function:

```
setInterval(moveElements, 100);
```

Thanks to @kumar_harsh for giving me the idea on how to solve the problem.

I tested this code in the following browsers, and it runs without lag/jiggle:

- Chrome 63
- Firefox 57
- Internet Explorer 11
- Microsoft Edge 16
- Safari 11

here my final **JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/2rrcp27L/27/

Comment: Are you cancelling the setInterval anywhere? If not, then it will keep calling itself even when user is not interacting with the page - eating away battery and resources.

Comment: I'd like to refer you to this post for a better understanding of throttling, and why using that is better than just a setInterval: https://medium.com/@_jh3y/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
-webkit-transform /* android, safari, chrome */

-moz-transform /* old firefox */

-o-transform /* old opera */

-ms-transform /* old IE */

transform   /*standard */
```

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud D. Alghraibeh thanks for your answer. but i've already tried that, that its still laggy in firefox. If I'm not mistaken, firefox does not need a a -moz- prefix for transitions: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Comment: To verify, browsers have not needed vendor prefixes for many years or versions except, of course, IE. This cannot be the solution.

Comment: I'd advise to not write code like this manually. You should use [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) to do it for you - it's much less maintenance, and you'll not have to worry about removing the IE and opera fallbacks when those browsers become too old to even matter. (for example, only 0.05% people use Opera 12.1 today - do you really need code for that?)

Comment: Also, I don't think this would actually do anything to improve perf in Firefox/IE. It's a rendering issue, not a CSS compatibility issue.

Comment: @Rob: "except, of course, IE", which has **never** needed prefixes for transitions in any stable version, and the only version that requires prefixes for transforms does not support transitions to begin with.

Comment: @BoltClock I was speaking of transforms without looking it up but it belies my point that vendor prefixes are not needed here.